# How do you bring up the equations for this Op-Amp numerical question?

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance, input-impedance

[image: op-am numerical]

How do you make the KCL/KVL equations for this circuit? Does input impedance means calculating overall circuit impedance?

Comment: The good, old [censored] simulator! It is not immediately clear, but you have negative feedback. So you know that Vp and Vn are equal for each separate op amp. Use a voltage test generator and try to calculate the current that goes into the circuit.

Comment: I doubt if your teacher would approve of that simulator based approach.

Comment: Are you required to find Zi using KCL/KVL or are you allowed to use simulation packages? The circuit represents Antoniou`s GIC block - extended with an additional resistor Ro. The result for Zin will consist of a positive and a negative part.

Comment: I'm required to use KVL/KCL using the old pen-paper method. No simulation based approach.

Comment: What have you tried?  \$ Z_{in} = \frac{V_{in}}{I_{in}} \$ Redraw the circuit labelling the nodes and any currents you are interested in including \$I_{in} \$ then you can apply Kirchoffs laws.  It's not too difficult to analyse. If you succeed post your own answer. If not show us where you where you are getting stuck and we will try to help further.  We need to see more effort from you though as we don't just do peoples homework for them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fixed classic Gyrator filter ( used extensively in audio graphic equalizers)  using negative feedback with impedance conversion of a Capacitor into an Inductor.

It can be  solved using [Millman’s Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millman%27s_theorem) or as a [SuperNode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernode_(circuit)) using KVL,KCL
[image]

Assume each  Op.Amp. differential input voltage = 0 and input current = 0 and output impedance = 0

Answer (score 0):

Representing Op Amps equivalent circuit as a voltage controlled voltage source with infinite gain, a network can be formed. To this network, given a voltage source of 1V across 1 and 1' terminals, current can be found from either nodal analysis or mesh analysis. Current flowing from source's inverse would give you impedance seen from source.

Comment: Which nodes do I use the nodal analysis on? Also, what's meant by "passive equivalent" as given in the question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are allowed to consider IDEAL opams, right?
In this case, you can make use of a "trick", which is based on redrawing the circuit. It is the aim to have two separate blocks (opamp with internal feedback loops) which are connected in series - and, thus, can be analyzed separately (no cross-coupling between both opams).

Each of these two blocks will be a "Negative Impedance Converter (NIC)" and it is very easy to calculate the input impedances for each NIC.

Here comes the trick: As we can see, the non-inverting inputs of both opamps will have the same voltage (zero diff. voltage between input terminals). Thus, you are allowed to interchange (swap) both "+" terminals.

Therefore, make a redrawing of the circuit including this modification and realize that the circuit consists of a NIC which is loaded by another NIC. In addition, the common node for the "-" terminals has a resistor to ground - that`s all. I know that it works! Try it.

(If necessary, start a google search for NIC, the input impedances are rather simple expressions)

Comment: By the way, the resulting circuit (after swapping the "+" terminals) is another known realization for a "Generalized Impedance Converter" (GIC).

**EDIT**: Regarding your last question (passive equivalent): When you arrive at the correct result for Zin, it will be possible for you to evaluate the result. In this case, you will see that there is (1) a frequency-dependent part which has some similarities with a very well known passive part and (2) another fixed (frequency-independent) part, which also is equivalent to a well-known passive part. Then, you will be able to answer the question.